# Data Compression Through Base36 Encoding

Tags: mysql, database-design, optimization

I'm trying to store a lot of large numbers that truncate when stored as `INT` values. Unfortunately they are too large for this type.

I'm thinking about using [Base36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) encoding to accomplish this. Are there any other ways to go about fixing this problem?

Comment: How big are the numbers? Bigger than `BIGINT` can store?

Comment: oh wow :p didn't know there was such a thing as BIGINT... I'm a C programmer at heart still

Answer (score 13, accepted):

More often than not, `Base36` encoding will lead to a loss of precision as the base conversion process requires floating point number operations. Not only will this corrupt your data when converting to and from `Base36`, you will also be consuming more space (`INT` takes up 4 bytes, many `Base36`-encoded integers near the 32-bit unsigned integral limit will take up more than this).

See [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php) for a thorough explanation on the loss of precision.

---

**Answer**: You should be using [BIGINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types) for your operations.

Answer (score 8):

You can use either,

the bigger than `INT`, integer [`BIGINT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html) datatype:

`BIGINT UNSIGNED`: values from `0` up to `2^64-1` (about `18 * 10^18`)

`BIGINT SIGNED`: values from `-2^63` up to `2^63-1` (about `-9 * 10^18` to `9 * 10^18`)

or fixed-point [`NUMERIC`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) (also named `DECIMAL`) datatype:

`DECIMAL(M, 0)`: values from   `-(10^M-1)` up to `10^M+1`

The `M` can be up to `65`, so you can store integers with up to 65 decimal digits.